# how to count how many values in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm new to python so I'm sure this is a simple answer but I'm trying to find how to count the number of values in a certain key in a dictionary from an input.

I've tried something like:

```
fruits = {'apple' : 1, 2, 3 , 'banana' : 4, 5, 6}
search_fruit = input('Enter the fruit name:')
count = len(fruits[search_fruit])
print(f'{search_fruit} has {count} values that are {fruits[search_fruit]}')
```

the output should be for example:
apple has 3 values that are 1 2 3

but instead i'm getting:
apple has 5 values that are 1 2 3

Comment: can't replicate... this code gives exactly the right answer you expect when I run it

Comment: is `fruits['apple']` a string and not actually a list?

Comment: hmm so I have it in a much larger program so my fruits come from another input and they are `{'apple': '1 2 3'}` instead of `{'apple' : [1, 2, 3,]}` so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That makes a very big difference. `'1 2 3'` has a length of 5. count everything in the string including space. And it is not numeric. So you need to ensure you get a list containing numeric and not a string.

Comment: @sunnymuffinz That's a string, not a list. Very different. Please [edit] the code in the question to reflect that. To convert, you could do `fruits = {k: v.split() for k, v in fruits.items()}`.

Answer (score 0):

Values should be either tuples (1, 2, 3), or lists [1, 2, 3]. The input function is not practical. An input variable works best. Hope this helps.!

```
input_key = "apple"
fruits = {'apple' : [1, 2, 3] , 'banana' : [4, 5, 6]}
length = len(fruits[input_key])
print(length)
```